# Criteria,Independent Subqueries, Group By and Having more

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a product table with a relationship to color table

a product can have many colors... exp: Product A: has red, green blue yellow.

```
Product
-----------
ProductID
Name

Color
-----------
ProjectID
Color
```

I wish to find the product which contain at least RED and GREEN

for dynamic size, I also wish to add name = "doggy"

The SQL statement is

```
select * from product pd where pd.ProductID = (select cr.productID from color cr where cr.color="RED" or cr.color="GREEN" group by  cr.productID having rowcount=2)
and name like '%doggy'
```

How do I create the Criteria, without dependent subqueries.

Question linked to

1) [Criteria, Subqueries, Group By and Having more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426562/criteria-subqueries-group-by-and-having-more/11427513#comment15074949_11427513)

2) [One to Many search using AND condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409302/one-to-many-search-using-and-condition/11411560#comment15076601_11411560)

As you can see, there is no good solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria colorCrit = DetachedCriteria.For(Product.class)
    .createAlias("colors","color")
    .add(Restriction.eq("color.color", "RED")
    .add(Restriction.eq("color.color", "GREEN")
    .SetProjection(new GroupByHavingProjection("id", Projections.count("id"), "=", 2));

Criteria criteria = createCriteria()
    .add(Subqueries.in("id", colorCrit)
    .list();
```

using the groupbyhaving implementation from [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1043?focusedCommentId=35459&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%253Acomment-tabpanel#action_35459) which looks like:

```
// (c) 2008-2010 FURTHeR Project, Health Sciences IT, University of Utah<br>
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projection;
import org.hibernate.criterion.PropertyProjection;

public class GroupByHavingProjection extends PropertyProjection
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3316795021430206470L;

    private final Projection havingProjection;
    private final String groupByProperty;
    private String op;
    private Object value;

    public GroupByHavingProjection(final String groupByProperty, final Projection projection, final String op, final Object value)
    {
        super(groupByProperty, true);
        this.projection = projection;
        this.groupByProperty = groupByProperty;
        this.op = op;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```